# Any Base to Binary

Tags: c, linux, binary

I am having an issue getting my C program to work. I am trying to take a positive number from the user and a base and convert that into binary. The bases can only range from 2-6. I am having trouble getting the binary value to be correct. I have copied my code below, if you see any errors or know why I am not getting the correct answer please help me.

```
#define MIN_BASE 2
#define MAX_BASE 16

int main()
{
        //Variale Declarations
        int num;
        int base;
        int binary;
        int remainder;
        int i;

        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        printf("Enter a base: ");
        scanf("%d", &base);

        if (base >= MIN_BASE &&  base <= MAX_BASE) {
                while( num > 0){
                        remainder = num % base;
                        num = num / base;
                        binary = remainder, binary;
                }
        }
        else {

                while(base < MIN_BASE || base > MAX_BASE){
                        printf("!! The base is invalid!!\n");
                        printf("Enter a base: ");
                        scanf("%d", &base);
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", binary);


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: For separating the digits shouldn't you be using `10` for remainder and division and then using the `base`? And which part of code is converting it into binary?

Comment: By using `scanf("%d"` you've already converted the user's input to base 10. You should probably input the user's number as a string, so you can properly interpret each digit.

Comment: The question says *"the bases can only range from 2-6"*, but in the code `MAX_BASE` is 16. Which of those is correct?

Comment: mickeyvolmouse, What do you expect `binary = remainder, binary;` to do?

Comment: @chux how bout that `else` clause....is OP expecting that to jump back to the `if` clause 0.o